# 7-Zip: Automate script with excluding folder but include its content(set folder as root itself) in .cbr structure

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, zip, 7-zip

When i use this script

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Programs\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.cbr" "%%X\"
```

in directory like this

```
mainfolder
  comicfolder1
    001.png
    002.png
  comicfolder2
    001.png
    002.png
```

results are

```
mainfolder
   comiczip1.cbr
      comicfolder1
         001.png
         002.png
   comiczip2.cbr
      comicfolder2
         001.png
         002.png
```

Because of this none of cbr readers can read these zip.

Which parameter should I use for getting this structure below?

```
mainfolder
   comiczip1.cbr
      001.png
      002.png
   comiczip2.cbr
      001.png
      002.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such switch or param in 7-zip to exclude the directory from the path. But you can achieve what you want if you change the actual directory before the compression.

```
for /d %%X in (*) do (
    pushd %%X
    "c:\Programs\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "..\%%X.cbr" ".\*"
    popd
)
```